# change html text from link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, hyperlink

a simple question here

Is there a way to change the text "click here"

```
<a id="a_tbnotesverbergen" href="#nothing">click here</a>
```

in this link

Richard

Answer (score 176):

You have to use the [jquery's text() function](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text). What it does is:

> **Get the combined text contents of all
> matched elements.**
>
> The result is a
> string that contains the combined text
> contents of all matched elements. This
> method works on both HTML and XML
> documents. Cannot be used on input
> elements. For input field text use the
> [val attribute](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val1).

For example:

> Find the text in the first paragraph
> (stripping out the html), then set the
> html of the last paragraph to show it
> is just text (the bold is gone).
>
> ```
> var str = $("p:first").text();
> $("p:last").html(str);
> ```
>
> **Test** Paragraph.
>
> Test Paragraph.

With your markup you have to do:

```
$('a#a_tbnotesverbergen').text('new text');
```

and it will result in

```
<a id="a_tbnotesverbergen" href="#nothing">new text</a>
```

Answer (score 63):

The method you are looking for is [jQuery's .text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text) and you can used it in the following fashion:

```
$('#a_tbnotesverbergen').text('text here');
```

Answer (score 30):

```
$('#a_tbnotesverbergen').text('My New Link Text');
```

OR

```
$('#a_tbnotesverbergen').html('My New Link Text or HTML');
```

Answer (score 14):

You need J-query library to do this simply:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

First you need to put your element in div like this:

```
<div id="divClickHere">
<a id="a_tbnotesverbergen" href="#nothing">click here</a>
</div>
```

Then you should write this J-Query Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#a_tbnotesverbergen").click(function(){
$("#divClickHere a").text('Your new text');
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this to be the simplest piece of code for getting the job done. As you can see it is super simple.

for
        original link text

I use:

```
    $("#sec1").text(Sector1);
```

where

```
   Sector1 = 'my new link text';
```

Answer (score 6):

From W3 Schools [HTML DOM Changes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp): If you look at the 3rd example it shows how you can change the text in your link, "click here".
Example:

```
<a id="a_tbnotesverbergen" href="#nothing">click here</a>
```

JS:

```
var element=document.getElementById("a_tbnotesverbergen"); 
element.innerHTML="New Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in javascript

```
 document.getElementById("22IdMObileFull").text ="itsClicked"
```