# jQuery href link

Tags: jquery, href, hyperlink

I have a link `<a id='id'>text1</a>`.

How can I set `<a id='id'>text2</a>` using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [change html text from link with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901909/change-html-text-from-link-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#id").text("text2");
```

Answer (score 1):

`.text()` method is there in jquery to set the text value.

check this : http://api.jquery.com/text/