# jQuery Change attritube of 'a' tag during toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I have an `<a` tag that calls a toggle function to remove a `<td` tag.  In that `a` tag I have `&lt;&lt;`...<<

In the function I want to change the `<<` to `>>` when the toggle is performed.  Its not working.  What am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<td class="filter_td" id="filter_td">
  <td class="show_hide">
            <a href="javascript:toggleFilters();" id="show_hide" alt="Hide Filters" title="Hide Filters">&lt;&lt;</a>
        </td>
```

jquery:

```
   function toggleFilters()
{
    var td = $("#filter_td");
    td.toggle('slow');
    if (td.css("display") == "none")
    {
        $("#show_hide").html("&gt;&gt;").attr('title', 'Show Filters');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#show_hide").html("&lt;&lt;").attr('title', 'Hide Filters');
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901909/change-html-text-from-link-with-jquery

Comment: not workng....`if (td.css("display") == "none")` is hitting the else statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code that changes the text into the callback for "toggle". That way, you know the animation is complete and the element's visible state is complete. Something like this:

```
var td = $("#filter_td");
td.toggle('slow', function () {
    if (td.not(":visible"))
    {
        $("#show_hide").html("&gt;&gt;").attr('title', 'Show Filters');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#show_hide").html("&lt;&lt;").attr('title', 'Hide Filters');
    }
});
```

Also, I changed the check for it being hidden to jQuery's ".not()". This is a more general way of telling if an element is actually visible on the page, instead of simply looking at its styling (which may not be defined).

Comment: where do I put the ending ')' for the toggle function?

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot to re-add that when I added the callback part. It's there now.

Comment: Ok....this is what happens.  I hit the "<<" it hides the td...and the arrows are still "<<".  When I press them again to show the td, they are ">>"

Comment: Hey ianpgall...is there a way to make another `td` that is next to the one Im hiding slide over instead of jump over

Comment: I have this under the td that im hiding during the toggle:  `<td class="content" id="content">`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#show_hide").on('click', function() {
    var td = $("#filter_td"),
        state = td.is(':visible');
    td.toggle('slow');
    $("#show_hide").html(state?"&gt;&gt;":"&lt;&lt;")
                   .prop('title', (state?'Hide':'Show')+' Filters');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TBg9D/1/)