# How to insert title of a html page into the text of an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a CMS and creating a breadcrumb in a page wrapper that will be applied to multiple pages, and what I wanted to do was

**Take the `<title>` of the page being viewed and insert it into the breadcrumb, the breadcrumb will dynamically change for each page.**

Unfortunately the CMS' internal built-in functions doesn't allow me to simply insert the `[[S80:frID]]` which pulls the page id # dynamically.

I have to manually input the page ID # which then removes the dynamic aspect. So I wanted to resort to Javascript

I'm certain I can retrieve the title by doing:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var pgTitle = document.title;

   $("#pullTitle").text(" " + pgTitle);

 });
</script>
```

but how would I take that and insert it into the text of an anchor tag:

```
<a id="#pullTitle" href="internalpage">  </a>
```

What I've tried above doesn't do anything. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Your using of jQuery's `text()` function is [okay](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901937/216084). Now, it could be that the breadcrumb is not available on `$(document).ready` if it is being dynamically created, or issue of duplicate IDs (as suggested by [Devin D](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40871820/216084))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is simply the # in the anchor ID. The # in the jquery selector tells it to look at element IDs (as opposed to a . for classes)

If you remove that this should work!

Comment: oh man I been doing every thing I could think of javascript/jquery related and it didn't even hit me that it was the # in the anchor tag lol thanks Devin, it finally works!

Answer (score 4):

Try:
`$("#pullTitle").html(" " + pgTitle)`;

This will result in:

```
<a id="pullTitle" href="internalpage">page title appears here</a>
```

Comment: # represents a id selector it need not be a part of the id. ID should be pullTitle and not #pullTitle

Comment: @Manish: Received your comment as I was correcting it :-).  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in javascript in 2 lines:

```
var titleBreadcrumb = document.getElementById('pullTitle');
titleBreadcrumb.textContent = document.title;
```

Or even just one line, if you want:

```
document.getElementById('pullTitle').textContent = document.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have added # character in anchor tag id. thats why its not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/a7w4yLd4/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Hello World</title>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   var pgTitle = $('title').text();

   $("#pullTitle").text(pgTitle);

 });
  </script>
<body>
<a id="pullTitle" href="internalpage">test  </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of this: 
1. $("#pullTitle").html(" " + pgTitle); or 
2. var titleBreadcrumb = document.getElementById('pullTitle');
titleBreadcrumb.textContent = document.title;