# how do you pass the value to anchor tag on every click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how do you pass the value to anchor tag on every click using jquery?
I have this code here.
I am trying to get value every time I click the button

```
//My HTML
<button id="a-selectNm" data-a_name="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#selectNm">SELECT nursemaid</a>

//The modal
<div class="modal" id="selectNm">
<div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">
        <a href="#a_name"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></a>
    </h4>
</div>
</div>

//My jQuery code
jQuery(document).on('click', 'button#a-selectNm', function() {
    var a_name = jQuery(this).data('a_name');
    jQuery('.modal a[href="#a_name"]').val(a_name);
});
</script>
```

What is my mistake? what do I have to change?

Comment: An anchor element (`<a>`) has no `value`

Comment: As there is no value attribute, try using `jQuery('.modal a[href="#a_name"]').text();`

Comment: It doesn`t work. Its still the first array passed on the anchor tag.

Comment: try `jQuery('.modal a[href="#a_name"]').text(a_name);`

Comment: Thanks it works now.

Comment: How about in header tag? is it possible to pass a value?

Comment: @harly john: you are welcome, here i added it as an answer, if helped please accept.

Comment: header tag means?

Comment: I meant this <h4> tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change html text from link with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901909/change-html-text-from-link-with-jquery)

Comment: For example I want to pass value that I clicked in the button to <h4> tag. Should I put like this <h4 href="#HERE">?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
jQuery('.modal a[href="#a_name"]').val(a_name);
```

with

```
jQuery('.modal a[href="#a_name"]').text(a_name);
```