# HTML anchor source is a dynamic field - how do I append text to the end of it?

Tags: html, src

I am building emails using HTML and CSS only, I cannot use jquery or any other language.

Here is an example of an anchor tag we use. The src is code is a dynamic field that is populated according to what campus a student attends. I need to add a line of code (for tracking emails) to the end of each URL. Is it possible to do this?

```
<a href="https://www.artinstitutes.edu/" target="_blank"><img class="center  autowidth " align="center" border="0" src="${Recipient.lead.dceh_campusid.dceh_campus.dceh_campuslogourl}" alt="The Art Institutes" title="The Art Institutes"/></a>
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change html text from link with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901909/change-html-text-from-link-with-jquery)

Comment: I'm using ClickDimensinos with Microsoft Dynamics 365. Yes, I just want to add the same text to all urls populated in src.